# Neo4J - count outermost nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Given a graph (or subgraph), in this case root Neo...

How do I get the nodes which are the furthest depth from the root (i.e not directly connected to nodes of greater depth) which have a specific attribute.

eg ... how do I get the green "Get Me" nodes when I'm not interested in the other green ones (they're not the outermost layers) or the orange ones (furthest out on their branch but not green). I don't care about depth ....

[image: how do I get the green "Get Me" nodes]

Thanks for your help

Chris

Comment: Should the path only consist of green nodes? Can the relationships be in any direction? Is the specific attribute a label or a property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach to Franks would be to find all the leaf nodes first that match your criteria, and then using those nodes, filter down to those that have a path to the Neo node

```
// find all Green nodes (you can add in a filter / WHERE clause to 
// just match the ones with specific properties)
MATCH (g:Green)--(o) 
// for each match, calculate the degree of the node (the number of 
// relationships - undirected in this example)
WITH g, count(*) as deg 
// filter down the results to just the leaf nodes (deg 1)
WHERE deg = 1
WITH g 
// finally only return those that have a path to the Blue (neo) node
MATCH (g)-[*]-(b:Blue) 
// just return the green nodes
RETURN g;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll address the case where the path should only contain green nodes (apart from the start node, maybe), because otherwise it can become really expensive to compute, since you'd need to find if there's another green node at any distance further.

Note: variable-length paths are unbounded in my examples, you might want to add an upper limit to avoid really slow queries.

## Option 1

Supposing the attribute is a label, and relationships can be traversed in any direction, you can use the following query:

```
MATCH p = (:Blue)-[*]-(g:Green)
WHERE all(n IN tail(nodes(p)) WHERE n:Green)
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)--(g2:Green)
WITH p, collect(g2) AS greens
WHERE size(greens) <= 1
RETURN last(nodes(p))
```

1. It finds paths that only consist of green nodes, except for the start node which can be anything.
2. It then collects all the other green nodes connected to the last node of the path. There should either be no such node, when the path is simply `(:Blue)--(g:Green)`, or only one, when the path is like `(:Blue)--(:Green)--(g:Green)`, i.e. the penultimate node of the path. If there's another green node connected, the path does not end at an outermost node.

It works almost the same if the attribute is a property:

```
MATCH p = (:Blue)-[*]-(g)
WHERE all(n IN tail(nodes(p)) WHERE n.prop = {value})
OPTIONAL MATCH (g)--(g2)
WHERE g2.prop = {value}
WITH p, collect(g2) AS greens
WHERE size(greens) <= 1
RETURN last(nodes(p))
```

## Option 2

You only traverse the relationships in one direction.

```
MATCH p = (:Blue)-[*]->(g:Green)
WHERE all(n IN tail(nodes(p)) WHERE n:Green)
AND NOT (g)-->(:Green)
RETURN last(nodes(p))
```